# É possível saber se uma array bidimensional esta vazia?

Tags: php, array

basicamente minha dúvida já esta esclarecida na pergunta.
É só isso, gostaria de saber se **é possível saber se uma array bidimensional esta vazia?**

*Agradeço desde já!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Nesse exemplo eu faço um *loop* no array `revenant` e imprimo todas os arrays que o compõem, que não estão vazios, ou seja, imprimo todos exceto o último array que compõe o array "principal".

Então, você só precisa verificar pela chave do array com a função [**`empty()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) do PHP se existe valores associados ao array interno.

Exemplo:

```html
<?php

$revenant = array(
        'cast' => array(
            'Leading Role' => 'Leonardo DiCaprio',
            'Supporting Actor' => 'Tom Hardy'
        ),
        'overview' => array(
            'Movie' => 'The Revenant',
            'Director' => 'Alejandro Iñárritu',
            'Year' => '2015'
        ),
        'details' => array()
);

foreach($revenant as $key => $val){
    if(!empty($val)){
        print_r($val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, eu tinha feito dessa forma antes de vc responder. Porem nao sabia se era a forma correta uma vez que para array simples o php ja tem função pronta pra cuidar disso.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Sem problemas! Boa sorte!!!